# How can I use the AWS C++ SDK to parse an S3 URI for region, bucket and object key?

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I have an S3 URI, and I need to extract the region, bucket and object key so that I can use the `Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest` to [upload an object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object).

Does the AWS C++ SDK provide a utility function for doing purpose? Should I use a regular expression?

I note that the AWS Java SDK provides [AmazonS3URI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.html), but I haven't found anything similar so far in the C++ SDK.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDK C++ provides Aws::Crt::Io::Uri which is general but you can definitely use it with s3.

```cpp
    const std::string s3uri("s3://mybucket/sample-file-name");
    Aws::Crt::Io::Uri uri(Aws::Crt::ByteCursor{s3uri.size(), (uint8_t*)s3uri.data()});
    std::cout << "Scheme:" << Aws::Utils::StringUtils::FromByteCursor(uri.GetScheme())
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Authority:"
              << Aws::Utils::StringUtils::FromByteCursor(uri.GetAuthority()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Path:" << Aws::Utils::StringUtils::FromByteCursor(uri.GetPath())
              << std::endl;
```

Results in

```
Scheme:s3
Authority:mybucket
Path:/sample-file-name
```

Two years late but I hope someone this helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't think C++ SDK supports it. But S3 URIs are just those - URIs. So any decent URI parser should be able to parse S3 URIs, your bucket name will be parsed as `host` and a file key will be parsed as `path`.